# Unity App: How to check available space left on Android / IOS device

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, storage

I am developing a game (iOS/Android with Unity Game Engine)  that requires to download resources to be stored locally on device. I wish to check free space on device to send an error message before download starts in case it's not enough.

How can I check it? I couldn't find any clear procedure on my research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies by platform so isn’t a simple answer. The free Unity plugin [Simple Disk Utils](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/simple-disk-utils-59382) handles it for you on Windows, Mac, Android and iOS and full source code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/dkrprasetya/simple-disk-utils) so you can see for yourself how it’s achieved on the different platforms.